# C# XML Serialization issue { get {...} }

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've been reading a lot of other so questions regarding c# xml serialization but I can't seem to get around this little understanding issue I have.

I hope its not too long, please consider the following code:

```
public class Grandparent {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}



public class ParentA : Grandparent {
    private Grandparent _neighbor;

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "neighbor")]
    public string NeighborName {  get { return _neighbor.Name; } }

    public ParentA() : this(null) { }
    public ParentA(Grandparent neighbor) {
        setNeighbor(neighbor);
    }

    public void setNeighbor(Grandparent neighbor) {
        // Do some checking
        _neighbor = neighbor;
    }
}



public class ParentB : Grandparent {
    private List<Grandparent> _people;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "child1")]
    public List<ChildA1> Children1 {  get { return _people.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(ChildA1)).Cast<ChildA1>().ToList(); } }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "child2")]
    public List<ChildA2> Children2 { get { return _people.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(ChildA2)).Cast<ChildA2>().ToList(); } }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "parentc")]
    public List<ParentC> ParentsC { get { return _people.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(ParentC)).Cast<ParentC>().ToList(); } }

    public ParentB() {
        _people = new List<Grandparent>();
    }

    public void AddPerson(Grandparent person) {
        // Do some checking
        _people.Add(person);
    }
}



public class ParentC : Grandparent {
}



public class ChildA1 : ParentA {
}



public class ChildA2 : ParentA {
}



[XmlRoot("myroot")]
public class Model {
    private List<ParentB> _parents;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "parentb")]
    public List<ParentB> Parents {  get { return _parents; } }

    public Model() {
        _parents = new List<ParentB>();
    }

    public void AddParent(ParentB parent) {
        // Do some checking
        _parents.Add(parent);
    }

    public string Serialize() {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And now lets create a model and fill it with some data:

```
Model model = new Model();

ChildA1 child1 = new ChildA1 { Name = "Alex" };
ChildA1 child2 = new ChildA1 { Name = "Ben" };
ChildA2 child3 = new ChildA2 { Name = "Jim" };
ChildA2 child4 = new ChildA2 { Name = "Pete" };

child1.setNeighbor(child2);
child2.setNeighbor(child1);
child3.setNeighbor(child4);
child4.setNeighbor(child3);

ParentB parent1 = new ParentB { Name = "Fred" };
ParentC parent2 = new ParentC { Name = "Sam" };

parent1.AddPerson(parent2);
parent1.AddPerson(child1);
parent1.AddPerson(child2);
parent1.AddPerson(child3);
parent1.AddPerson(child4);

model.AddParent(parent1);

textBox1.Text = model.Serialize();
```

This is the output xml we get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<myroot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <parentb name="Fred">
    <child1 name="Alex" />
    <child1 name="Ben" />
    <child2 name="Jim" />
    <child2 name="Pete" />
    <parentc name="Sam" />
  </parentb>
</myroot>
```

Now we finally come to the cause of my problem:
From my understanding only public data will be serialized, that means methods (or the data returned from them) will not be serialized.
So something like `public string Test { get; set; }` might translate to a public field... so that might be serialized.
But what about this: `public string Test { get { return _someString; } }`?
Thats just syntactic sugar for a normal method like `public string get_Test() { return _someString; }` isn't it? And we know data returned from methods is not being serialized right?

And yes, there is the proof:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "neighbor")]
public string NeighborName {  get { return _neighbor.Name; } }
```

This is not being serialized.
But wait.. what? The following one works:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "child1")]
public List<ChildA1> Children1 {  get { return _people.Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(ChildA1)).Cast<ChildA1>().ToList(); } }
```

I guess I could argue that some simple getter like `public string Test { get { return _someObj.someString; } }` is just accessing a datafield and *might* translate to something that could be serialized? But the more complex getter posted above does indeed work, why would the simple version (neighbor) not work?
I must be missing something... it's starring me in the eye but I just can't see it.

Please help me solve this riddle.

PS: The classes and code above is just a rebuild of the Code that actually brought up this problem. Its structure is similar and the output produced is also pretty similar. I did implement and test this code in an application real quick and it seems to show my problem, please forgive me if there is some mistake I made when cloning the basic structure of the original code.

Comment: Is it intended that one is decorated with `XmlAttribute` and the other one with `XmlElement` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read only properties are not serialized, because they can't be deserialized back into the object data on the round trip.

However, there is an exception to the rule for read only properties that return collections -> `IEnumerable`.

What the deserializer does on the round trip back (when xml becomes a class again), is add elements as types to the collection. It never has to "set" the property.

*Note: In your case if you did try to deserialize it would bomb. But if  you changed it to use a backing field it would not bomb.*

See [Introducing XML Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(VS.85).aspx) and note 3rd paragraph:

> XML serialization does not convert methods, indexers, private fields,
>   or read-only properties (except read-only collections). To serialize
>   all an object's fields and properties, both public and private, use
>   the BinaryFormatter instead of XML serialization.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. So what is best practice in my case then? I always want the neighbor attribute to be the name of the neighbor, so I could just `private Grandparent _neighbor; private string _neighborName;` and make the setter: `public string NeighborName {  get { return _neighbor != null ? _neighbor.Name : _neighborName; } set { _neighborName = value; } }`. I think this is a bad solution because someone using this class might think he can set the NeighborName property but it's just kinda shadowed by the Name of the real neighbor property (and I don't want to change that objects props).

Comment: If it's always deserialized to create it, you can set a private flag to allow it to be set only once, and throw invalid operation exception after that